# Build and Move a simple human character model in rViz

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys!

I'd like to build a simple human model in rViz and be able to move it.
Actually, something pretty similar to this little app which I've developed using Ogre and Qt:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0WP0kd4sOU&feature=youtu.be

Here I could basically map the output from each inertial sensor,to the corresponding character body segment.
Is it possible to achieve the same in rViz?
Do you have any suggestion or sample code to share?
By the way,  even a simple "stickman" model could be enough :)

Thanks everybody!

Luca

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46695/build-and-move-a-simple-human-character-model-in-rviz/) by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 706 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-10-25**:
Does the video this page (http://www.ros.org/wiki/skeleton_markers) count as a simple stickman model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also think RVIZ might not be the best choice for this purpose. You can take a look at the MORSE simulator. It's a simulator based on Blender and comes with a human model that can be controlled using Kinect (also via ROS) like in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qaLBoGTQEI  (from 00:12s)

It's open-source, so you can also take a look at the code. You find more information here:

http://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you very much for the suggestions guys!
I have been thinking about rViz just because I don't need any physical computation, but rather just a plain visualization tool.
I will give a try to MORSE which seems to be more suitable to my human-interfaced application.

Have a nice day!

Luca

---

Originally posted by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) with karma: 706 on 2012-10-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1